# Ошибка при создании подписанного приложения android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, app

После обновления, а может само обновление и не виновато, не знаю, у меня не получается создать подписанное приложение. Я хочу сделать именно app-release. У меня почему-то возникли проблемы с картинками из папки drawable. Вот ошибка:

```
../../src/main/res/drawable-en-mdpi/flag.xml:1: The drawable "flag" in drawable-en-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier
```

вот сама картинка:

```
<vector android:autoMirrored="true" android:height="64dp"                                           
android:viewportHeight="512" android:viewportWidth="512"
android:width="64dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#41479B" android:pathData="M503.172,423.725H8.828c-4.875,0 -8.828,-3.953 -8.828,-8.828V97.104c0,-4.875 3.953,-8.828 8.828,-8.828h494.345c4.875,0 8.828,3.953 8.828,8.828v317.793C512,419.772 508.047,423.725 503.172,423.725z"/>
```

у меня вообще три таких картинки и поэтому три подобных ошибки. Хотя до обновы таких проблем не было. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Надеюсь что поможете разобраться, может у кого-то уже была подобная ситуация.

Comment: у вас не в каждой необходимой папке есть нужный файл. Все файлы должны быть в продублированы в соответствующих папках без спецификаторов (`en` или `-mdpi` как у вас) и в папках с ними.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, не очень понял если честно. Вы хотите сказать что нужно добавить эти файлы в папку `drawable` ту где висят все картинки из приложения?

Comment: Да, в общую папку. Потому что если кто-то запустит ваше приложение не в `en` локализации - программа не найдет нужный ресурс и крашнется.

Comment: да я вот как-раз нашел это на сайте гугла)) но у меня например три картинки с одинаковым названием

Comment: Собственно, вот смысл ошибки: `flag.xml has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder`

Comment: просто я не думаю что картинки с одинаковыми названиями добавятся в одну папку

Comment: по идее, ваш `flag` в папке `drawable-en-mdpi`, а не в `drawable`. Нажмите `Show in Explorer`

Comment: да совершенно верно, у меня три папки для трех картинок

Comment: и надо еще добавить в общую: `drawable`

Comment: так как я добавлю три файла с одинаковым названием, вот например я докинул в папку англ версию этой картинки, и все нормально, но осталось две еще картинки с таким же названием, и они предлагают перезаписать англ версию

Comment: сделайте это в эксплорере, если нужно - создайте папки)

Comment: можно с этого места поподробнее, я в эксплорере в папке `drawable` там пока есть только англ картинка, пробую перекинуть еще русскую картинку и мне предлагают перезаписать англ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83665/discussion-between-jarvis-j-and-andrew-goroshko).